# MySql Select Where or Where not... while many other "Ands" and "Ors"

Tags: php, sql, select, where-clause

What am I doing wrong?

I want to select Churches that are Catholic Only but it is selecting more. Is it because of the Zips? they work great.

```
$Zips = array(60618,60625,60647,60641,60613,60657,60640,60659,60614,60639,60622,60630,60660,60651,60642,60645,60712,60612,60646,60624,60610,60626,60674,60654,60661,60644,60634,60606,60607,60707,60302,60611,60202,60602,60601,60706,60303,60603,60604,60301,60701,60656,60076,60204,60209,60304,60077,60623,60608,60305,60203,60605,60631,60664,60668,60669,60670,60673,60675,60677,60678,60680,60681,60684,60685,60686,60687,60688,60690,60691,60693,60694,60696,60697,60699,60689,60695,60171,60201,60682,60208,60053,60804,60714,60616,60130,60161,60153,60176,60068,60160,60029,60141,60091,60402,60632,60131,60290,60165,60609,60043,60164,60546);
$ZipCount = count($Zips);

for ($i = 0; $ZipCount > $i; $i++) {
    if ($i == 0) {
        $TheZips = "Zip LIKE '%$Zips[$i]%'";
    }
    else {
        $TheZips .= "OR Zip LIKE '%$Zips[$i]%'";
    }
}

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT * FROM info WHERE Catholic and '%true%' OR $TheZips");
$result = mysql_num_rows($sql);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$str_zips = implode(', ', $Zips);

$sql = 
mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT * FROM info WHERE Catholic=true AND Zip IN ({$str_zips})");
```

Answer (score 3):

IMHO you should use:

```
for($i=0;$ZipCount>$i;$i++)
{
  if($i==0){  $TheZips= "Zip = '$Zips[$i]'"; }
  else {  $TheZips.= "OR Zip = '$Zips[$i]'";} 
}    

$sql = mysql_query(
  "SELECT DISTINCT * FROM info WHERE Catholic=true AND ($TheZips)");
```

or

```
for($i=0;$ZipCount>$i;$i++)
{
  if($i==0){  $TheZips= "$Zips[$i]"; }
  else {  $TheZips.= ",$Zips[$i]";} 
}    

$sql = mysql_query(
  "SELECT DISTINCT * FROM info WHERE Catholic=true AND Zip IN ($TheZips)");
```

Comment: Use implode() instead of a for-loop.

Comment: @Robin Castlin: yes, you're right, but I don't want to copy your good answer (+1 for you) :)